# How to select rows that contain specific number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table and want to select rows that contain exactly "22".

```
id   field
1    22
2    22,24,78
3    1,22,347
4    2,21,22
5    22,222
```

Select above rows, not below.

```
6    222
7    21,23
8    220,322
```

Comment: Then take a look at a beginners Database Design tutorial and refactor you database. Comma delimited lists of keys add nothing but complexity to the SQL you will have to write to process them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `REGEXP` operator comes in handy here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE field REGEXP '[[:<:]]22[[:>:]]';
```

We can also try using `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('22', field) > 0;
```

If all else fails, we *can* use `LIKE`, but it takes slightly more heavy lifting:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONCAT(',', field, ',') LIKE '%,22,%';
```

But in general, it is bad practice to store CSV (comma separated values) in your database tables.  It would be better to store each `field` value on a separate rows, e.g. use this:

```
id   field
1    22
2    22
2    24
2    78
...
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from  where field like '%22%';

Comment: This will also match `222`.